# How to calculate the amount of overlap between images?

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing

How to calculate the amount of overlap between images? I'm stitching two images and I need to know the minimum overlap that is enough to stitch the two images I need to calculate the overlap between images. I use the Python language.

Comment: If you shot the two images in controlled lighting with a tilt-shift lens on a tripod, the answer might be 1 row of pixels. If you were hand-held, outside, with a wide-angle lens and you rotated and tilted the camera between shots, you might want 50% overlap.

Answer (score 0):

> How to calculate the amount of overlap between images?

You perform an image registration and the result of it will automatically give you an overlap (if there is any).

To calculate the overlap, compute the bounds of both images (after overlaying) and then compute the bound of the intersection. The intersecting rectangle of two bounding rectangles [x1,y1,w1,h1] and [x2,y2,w2,h2] (both left upper corner, width, height) and  is [max(x1,x2),max(y1,y2),min(x1+w1,x2+w2)-max(x1,x2),min(y1+h1,y2+h2)-max(y1,y2)] (only if the resulting width and height is positive).

There are routines for image registration in in the popular Python packages: scikit, open-cv or itk.

In case, the images only need to be shifted to be overlaid, the maximum of a cross-correlation of two images (normalized by the overlapping area) is something that is commonly used.

> I need to know the minimum overlap that is enough to stitch the two images

The absolute minimum overlap required is a single line. In practice I would be worried about the uncertainty of the computation of the overlap (should be smaller with increasing overlap) as well as non-homogeneous imaging conditions (vignetting for example). Both should favor a somewhat larger overlap.